# Get first Record from laravel repository

Tags: laravel

I have searched it in google but could not get any related information. I want to know how can i get single (fisrt) record from laravel repository like the way we can easily do it from model.
For example

```
$student = Student::first();
```

but how can i get this when using repository, the following code does not work

```
$student = $this->studentRepo->first(); //gives an error Call to undefined method App\Repositories\Admin\studentRepository::first()

here is Repository
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Admin;

use App\Models\Admin\SystemSetting;
use App\Repositories\BaseRepository;

/**
 * Class SystemSettingRepository
 * @package App\Repositories\Admin
 * @version March 10, 2020, 11:27 am UTC
*/

class studentRepositoryextends BaseRepository
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fieldSearchable = [
        'first_name', 'allow_email', 'payment_charges', 'payment_days'
    ];

    /**
     * Return searchable fields
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFieldsSearchable()
    {
        return $this->fieldSearchable;
    }

    /**
     * Configure the Model
     **/
    public function model()
    {
        return User::class;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your repository class look like? Do you use any packages for repositories?

Comment: It is a simple repo

Comment: That doesn't help much. So simple it lacks the `first()` method. It doesn't seem to be there. Create it in your repo if you want to use it

Comment: `Student` model hasMany relationship with `StudentRepo` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a repository a wrapper around your model. So write a wrapper function:

```
class studentRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    ...
    function first()
    {
        return Student::first();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did the same before your answer and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `first()` method is a generic method we will put it into BaseRepository and because of that other repositories can use `first` method as well

```php
class studentRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fieldSearchable = [
        'first_name', 'allow_email', 'payment_charges', 'payment_days'
    ];

    /**
     * Return searchable fields
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFieldsSearchable()
    {
        return $this->fieldSearchable;
    }

    /**
     * Configure the Model
     **/
    public function model()
    {
        return User::class;
    }
}
```

```php
class BaseRepository
{
    public $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setModel($this->model());
    }

    // We will make sure that every repository class that extends BaseRepository must define model method in it.
    abstract public function model();

    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = app($model); // or $this->model = new $model
    }

    public function first()
    {
        return $this->model->first(); // or $this->model::first() #Whatever you feel normal.
    }
}
```

And here is an example usage

```php
class WhateverController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var \App\Project\V1\Controllers\Result\studentRepository
     */
    private studentRepository $studentRepository;

    public function __construct(studentRepository $studentRepository)
    {
        $this->studentRepository = $studentRepository;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return $this->studentRepository->first();
    }
}
```